# Perl CGI : Error message: <br />malformed header from script. Bad header=&lt;body&gt;:

Tags: perl, cgi

I am encountering the above error.

The main script is under below

```
#!/opt/lampp/bin/perl
use lib "/opt/lampp/htdocs/PERL";
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use WEBPAGE::PageDesign;
use HTML::Form;

my $header = get_header() ;
my $html   = parse_form(\%ENV);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<HTML;
$header
$html
HTML
```

The html generated is being proper, yet the script with html page followed by the error

```
Error message:
<br />malformed header from script. Bad header=&lt;body&gt;: publish_scholarship.pl,
```

Comment: Use Dumper and print $header and $html vars to console in order to see what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the print header line to the top. If it still not working then move it to BEGIN block.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
}

use lib "/opt/lampp/htdocs/PERL";
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use WEBPAGE::PageDesign;
use HTML::Form;


my $header = get_header() ;
my $html   = parse_form(\%ENV);

print <<HTML;
$header
$html
HTML
```